# maslov index of a holomorphic disk

Tags: heegaard-floer-homology

I am studying some introductory papers on heegard floer homology and I do not understand the meaning of the Maslov index of a holomorphic disk. I could not find any definition in any of the papers. I want to know the meaning of Maslov index here, otherwise I know it is also the expected dimension of the moduli space of the holomorphic representatives of the whitney disks between two points.

Comment: Interesting, because there is a whole website: http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/maslov.htm

Comment: I have seen the website, but I'd rather someone tell me the answer so that I do not have read through the whole website. I do not know much about Maslov index, I somewhat know the definition for a curve in a Lagrangian manifold, but it is not clear to me how to relate that to the above.

Comment: You should look at some standard reference in symplectic topology: I suggest McDuff-Salamon "Holomorphic curves in symplectic topology" or Seidel's book. Then, you can look at Lipshitz's paper "A cylindrical reformulation of Heegaard Floer homology" where he proves the combinatorial formula for the Maslov indexin Heegaard Floer homology.